# Does purchasing a mobile home allow you to lower your income tax?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, first-time-home-buyer, home

I have heard that by owning a home that your federal income tax is reduced. Does this still apply to mobile homes? If so, how much reduction could I expect? I currently have a tax rate of 28%. Living in a state with no income tax, but has property tax.

Would I be able to write-off repairs on this mobile home?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Paying *interest* on a *mortgage* on your residence allows you to deduct the interest, but only if all of your itemized deductions (mortgage interest, charitable donations, qualified medical expenses) are more that the standard deduction.  So it only  "lowers your taxes" to the extent that it gives you a bigger deduction.

Property tax is deductible as well, but also would only help you if the total deductions are more that the standard deduction for you or your family.

And yes, it applies to a mortgage on a mobile home (or condo, but not rent on an apartment since you don't "own" it). It does *not* apply to properties you own but do not live in (e.g. rentals)

> Would I be able to write-off repairs on this mobile home?

No.

Comment: So in theory if I paid 300 dollars interest, I would only be able to write off that 300 as a deduction?

Comment: Property tax deduction as well. Where I live, it's a significant amount. I'm paying an amount equal to 1/2 of my principal+interest in property tax. (So e.g. my P+I is 1000/month and my property tax is 6000/year. Those aren't the real numbers, but they are the real proportions I'm paying.)

Comment: @MattCrandall Correct. only the _interest_ is deductible.

Comment: +1 to D Stanley, there are other things to consider:  tax policy can change and mobile homes tend to depreciate greatly.  So in theory, a year after you make such a purchase the deduction could go away, and in about 5 years the home could be worth half of what you paid.

Comment: @shoover: Me too, Texas?

Comment: @shoover Property tax doesn't necessarily apply to a mobile home.  Can depend upon the state and year manufactured.  For example: https://www.boe.ca.gov/proptaxes/faqs/manfacthomes.htm (question 2).

Comment: Excuse me but is the property tax really deductible from income taxation in USA?

Comment: Note that property tax and mortgage interest on rental properties are both deductible as business expenses. Combined with depreciation, this is often enough to give a paper loss with positive cash flow.

Comment: @Ross Millikan:  You can deduct either state & local income tax or state & local sales tax.  Independently of which you choose, you can also deduct real estate and property tax .  https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc500/tc503

Comment: I think a couple of points need to be made explicit.  1) Yes, in theory a mortgage on a mobile home would be deductible, but you would be unlikely to find one where the purchase price is high enough to actually create a deduction.  (Unless it's on a large acreage, with most of the value in the land.)  2) Repairs & maintenance can be partially deductible if you're self-employed and use part of your home for work.  See IRS regs for details.